# Determine if $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}i]$ is UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Determine if $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}i]$ is UFD.

I was trying to prove this statement but, I don't know how to do this, once I don't know any result that establishes a sufficient and necessary condition for an integral domain be UFD.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know any sufficient conditions?

Comment: If you mean $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, then it is a Euclidean domain with respect to the usual norm, so a UFD.

Comment: Thanks mr. John Brevik, now I realized how to do this. In fact, one way to do this exercise is showing that this euclidean domain is a PID. I did it. 

Mr. André Nicolas, in fact I intend to say $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}i]$, how I did. But your remark was very importante. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb Z[i\sqrt2]$ is a UFD because it is a Euclidean domain. Consider the norm function $$N\colon \mathbb Z[i\sqrt2] \longrightarrow \mathbb Z,\quad a+i\sqrt2b\longmapsto \lvert a+i\sqrt2b\rvert^2 =a^2+2b^2.$$

Let now $x,y\in \mathbb Z[i\sqrt2]$ arbitrary, such that $y\neq 0$. Choose $q\in \mathbb Z[i\sqrt2]$ such that
$$\left\lvert\frac xy -q\right\rvert \le \left\lvert \frac xy-q'\right\rvert,\qquad \forall q'\in \mathbb Z[i\sqrt2].$$
Set $r:= x-qy\in \mathbb Z[i\sqrt2]$. Then we have $\left\lvert \frac xy-q\right\rvert\le \frac{\sqrt3}2$ (look at the lattice $\mathbb Z[i\sqrt2]$ defines in the complex plane). It follows that
$$\begin{align*}
N(r) &= N(x-qy) = \lvert y\rvert^2\cdot \left\lvert \frac xy-q\right\rvert^2\\
&\le \lvert y\rvert^2\cdot \frac34 < N(y).
\end{align*}$$
Hence $\mathbb Z[i\sqrt2]$ is a Euclidean domain and in particular a UFD.